# In viewmodels, is it bad practice to put common fields in a base class and inherit from this?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

If I have a number of pages that all have 3 common fields, is it recommended to have a base view model class that contains these 3 fields, and then on the viewmodels for each page, inherit from this base class?

I read somewhere that this was bad practice, but I’m not sure why. As it’s removing duplication and the validation still works etc.

Thanks

Jenny

Comment: pretty opinion-based. my two cents: are those fields _semantically_ related?, or are they just the same _by chance_?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using composition rather than inheritance. Put these 3 fields in a separate class and have a property of this class in each view model that needs them.

Composition tend to be a bit more flexible than inheritance. A typical example would be that you can only inherit from one class, but you can have as many properties as you would like.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is bad practice as your project gets more complex you will need to make changes to your fields and one template you use as base class might contain different amount of fields than you needed initially.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).